# Sharepoint formatting datetime from xml eg: 2011-12-15T00:00:00+01:00

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, powershell, dataset

I saved a sharepoint list to xml using dataset. DateTime is saved in this kind of format in xml:

```
<ExpiryDate>2011-12-15T00:00:00+01:00</ExpiryDate>
```

I tried to use CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime to read the datetime string back and add it to sharepoint field, but is it not working.

Code that I am using to save the data backed to sharepoint list item:

```
 $item["ExpiryDate"] =  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime([System.DateTime]$ExpiryDate.InnerText)}
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.

    At C:\PowershellFiles\ToList.ps1:122 char:31
    +                         $item[ <<<< "ExpiryDate"] =  [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime([System.DateTime]$ExpiryDate.InnerText)}
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MioExcoApprovalDate:String) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: "not working" is pretty vague. Please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added some more info. Hope this will help a bit. let me know if you need more info.

Comment: That looks like it has nothing to do with what's on the RHS of the assignment operator - it's assigning to `$item["ExpiryDate"]` which is failing.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the help. Yes, the problem seems to be with the field "ExpiryDate". I tried it with a different DateTime field and it is working fine. There must be something wrong in the configuration of this particual field that is causing the error.Thanks a lot for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: should not it be `item("ExpiryDate")` with `()` instead of `[]` ?